# QTextStream::readAll returns empty QString

Tags: c++, qt, qtextstream

I was trying to loop through all children of specific XML node and join their `name` attributes. The structure:

```
<params>
    <param name="BLAH" />
</params>
```

The desired result:

```
PARAM1='$PARAM1',PARAM2='$PARAM2',PARAM3='$PARAM3'[...]
```

The code:

```
    // Create empty text stream
    QTextStream paramNames("");
    // Start looping child by child
    QDomElement child = params.firstChildElement();
    bool firstIteration = true;
    while( !child.isNull() ) {  
        QString param_name = child.attribute("n");
        // Skips empty names
        if(param_name.length()>0) {
          // This prevents both leading and trailing comma
          if(!firstIteration)
              paramNames<<",";
          else
              firstIteration = false;
          // This should fill in one entry
          paramNames<<param_name<<"='$"<<param_name<<'\'';
        }
        child = child.nextSiblingElement();
    }
```

Now even the debugger says that if I do

```
QString paramNamesSTR = paramNames.readAll();
```

the `paramNamesSTR` is an empty string. However if I use `std` library instead, everything works:

```
    std::stringstream paramNames("");
    QDomElement child = params.firstChildElement();
    bool firstIteration = true;
    while( !child.isNull() ) {  
        std::string param_name = child.attribute("n").toUtf8().constData();
        if(param_name.length()>0) {
          if(!firstIteration)
              paramNames<<",";
          else
              firstIteration = false;
          paramNames<<param_name<<"='$"<<param_name<<'\'';
        }
        child = child.nextSiblingElement();
    }
    QString paramNamesSTR = QString::fromStdString( paramNames.str() );
```

So what's the difference? Why does the Qt `QTextStream` return empty string? I would really prefer to be consistent with used libraries and therefore use the `QTextStream` rather than `std::stringstream`, although presonally, I prefer the former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to use `QTextStream` you need to pass it something to operate on (the stream itself doesn't store any data, it just operates on a string or iodevice). Passing it a string literal is not the right thing to do. The difference is when you create the `std::stringstream` and pass it a string literal, an underlying stream buffer is created automatically, and that literal is used as the buffer's initial value. In case of `QTextStream`, that created a read-only stream that contains the passed literal. The right way to create a `QTextStream` would be to create the buffer first, and then create the stream to operate on that buffer, for example:

```
QString string; //you can also use a QByteArray, or any QIODevice
QTextStream stream(&string);
```

Comment: And do I access the stream full value using that original `QString`, or do I still call `readAll`? If it saves data in `QString`, ins't it just as good as using `QString`'s `operator+`?

Comment: @TomášZato, you can do it either way.

Comment: I tested the code and it does work, so thanks. However I'm little but unsire whether I should even bother with `TextStream` when it behaves just as if I just used `+` to join the strings...

Comment: @TomášZato, QTextStream has `>>` operators, padding, and other stuff which QString lacks. However if you are only accumulating string data and do not require any of those, you might as well use QString. QString's `operator+` is really fast because QString preallocates space in a special way, so performance should not be a problem.